# Can you find if two columns in a data set are in the same position?

Tags: javascript, datatable, code.org

I'm trying to compare two variables and find out if they have the same position to display the second variable, I'm trying to find out the second variable **(Artist name)** based off of the first input which was the **Track Name**, based off of the position on the data table.

All the track names are on the same position as the artist who made the song so I want to be able to display that when they input it.

My Code so far to choose the track name based off of a drop down with all 200 songs.

```
onEvent("fighter1", "change", function( ) {

    var Track = getProperty("fighter1", "text");

    setProperty("songLabel_1", "text", "");

    var ChosenTrack = Track.substring (0,100);

    var TrackName = getColumn("Spotify Charts: Top 200 Artist and Song", "Track");

    for (var i = 0; i < TrackName.length; i++) {
        if (ChosenTrack == TrackName) {   
        }
        setProperty("songLabel_1", "text", ChosenTrack);
    }
});
```

How would I structure it so that when the Track chosen pulls up its corresponding artist and displays it on a different label?

I'm using Code.org to program this.